# how to change the position of the property sheet wizard buttons?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am having a property sheet wizard which consists of three buttons Back,Next,Cancel as default at the right bottom corner.Do we have any possibility of moving those wizard buttons towards it's left to the center bottom of the sheet (exactly to the sheet center at the bottom,in detail those buttons should move towards their left to the center of the sheet)?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes.  You'll need to derive your own CPropertySheet class and override OnInitDialog () to move the buttons.  You need to use the IDs **ID_WIZNEXT** and **ID_WIZBACK** to get a pointer to the actual buttons.  Once you have the pointer, you can move the buttons just like you would any other control using CWnd::MoveWindow.  Here's some sample code (lacking error checking)...

```
CWnd* pWnd = GetDlgItem(ID_WIZBACK);
    CRect rect(0, 0, 0, 0);

    pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    rect.OffsetRect(-50, 0);
    ScreenToClient(&rect);
    pWnd->MoveWindow(&rect);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.See I want them to be moved to the center of the sheet.Doing as you suggested the control's will be moving towards their left,but how can we that they have been moved exactly to the center of the wizard sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Your original post asked how to "moving those wizard buttons towards it's left to the center bottom of the sheet (exactly to the sheet center at the bottom,in detail those buttons should move towards their left to the center of the sheet)".  My sample code shows how to move the 'Back' button to the **left** (center) 50 units.  It's not difficult to calculate the actual center of the sheet and adjust the movement accordingly.